# Navbar not working properly in ant design

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, navbar, antd

I am creating a project using React and ant design. I have created the navbar but it is not getting rendered properly. I am able to select an option but I cannot deselect it (like shown in the image, the project is in the initial stage so everything is a little misaligned). You can view the site here: http://192.168.56.1:3000/ .I am providing the code for app.js and navbar.jsx  [image]

App.js:

```js
const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="app">
      <div className="navbar">
        <Navbar />
      </div>
      <div className="main">
        <Layout>
          <div className="routes">
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/">
                <Homepage />
              </Route>
              <Route exact path="/cryptocurrencies">
                <Cryptocurrencies />
              </Route>
              <Route exact path="/exchanges">
                <Exchanges />
              </Route>
              <Route exact path="/news">
                <News />
              </Route>
              <Route exact path="/crypto/:coinId">
                <CryptoDetails />
              </Route>
            </Switch>
          </div>
        </Layout>
        <div className="footer">
          <Typography.Title level={5} style={{ color: 'white', textAlign: 'center' }}>
            Krypton <br />
          All rights reserved
        </Typography.Title>
          <Space>
            <Link to="/">Home</Link>
            <Link to="/exchanges">Exchanges</Link>
            <Link to="/news">News</Link>
          </Space>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Navbar.jsx:

```js
const Navbar = () => {

    return (
        <div className="nav-container">
            <div className="logo-container">
                <Avatar src={icon} size="large" />
                <Typography.Title level={2} className="logo">
                    <Link to="/">Krypton</Link>
                </Typography.Title>
                {/* <Button className="menu-control-container">

                </Button> */}
            </div>
            <Menu theme="dark">
                <Menu.Item icon={<HomeOutlined />}>
                    <Link to="/">Home</Link>
                </Menu.Item>
            </Menu>
            <Menu theme="dark">
                <Menu.Item icon={<FundOutlined />}>
                    <Link to="/cryptocurrencies">Cryptocurrencies</Link>
                </Menu.Item>
            </Menu>
            <Menu theme="dark">
                <Menu.Item icon={<MoneyCollectOutlined />}>
                    <Link to="/exchanges">Exchanges</Link>
                </Menu.Item>
            </Menu>
            <Menu theme="dark">
                <Menu.Item icon={<BulbOutlined />}>
                    <Link to="/news">News</Link>
                </Menu.Item>
            </Menu>
        </div>
    );
}
```